# Homebrew install libxml2 with python modules

Tags: python, macos, libxml2, homebrew

Good morning,

I'm trying to install libxml2 with python modules.  I have tried the following:

```
brew install --with-python libxml2                                                                  
==> Downloading ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/brandon/Library/Caches/Homebrew/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0 --without-python
```

As you can see... even with the --with-python flag, it is still configuring the source without python!

At the end of the install, homebrew says:

```
Generally there are no consequences of this for you.
If you build your own software and it requires this formula, you'll need
to add its lib & include paths to your build variables:

    LDFLAGS  -L/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/lib
    CPPFLAGS -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/include
```

When I try to install the gnome-doc-utils package:

```
Gnome-doc-utils requires libxml2 to be compiled
with the python modules enabled, to do so:
  $ brew install libxml2 --with-python
```

So obviously I tried again...

```
╰─ brew install libxml2 --with-python
Error: libxml2-2.8.0 already installed
```

I'm still new to this... so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any reason to not use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) (or [easy_install](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html) as a last resort)? They use to behave much better than other packaging tools - and work with [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/)!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, you cannot install libxml2 because you already successfully installed it, so you will first need to uninstall it.

`brew uninstall libxml2`

Next you will need to edit the brew formula - which is simple enough to do --

type
`brew edit libxml2` and change the line

```
system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}", "--without-python"
```

to this:

```
system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}", "--with-python"
```

This does not fix the problem with the brew formula, but it does force the flag "--with-python", so the next time you type `brew install libxml2` it will install the python libraries.

If you need to reset the formula (undo your changes), simply type `brew update`

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my problem after searching for quite a while!

Comment: I tried this but `make install` failed with `*** [install-am] Error 2` and `*** [install-recursive] Error 1`.

Comment: Use `brew install --build-from-source libxml2` after editing libxml2 if it uses the bottled version.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me. First unlink/uninstall if done previously:

```
brew unlink libxml2
brew unlink libxslt
brew uninstall libxml2
brew uninstall libxslt
```

Then

```
brew install --framework python
brew install --with-python libxml2
brew install --with-python libxslt
brew link libxml2 --force
brew link libxslt --force
```

Voila!

Comment: This helped me with fixing some issues I was having with using the lxml parser in Beautifulsoup with a brew installed version of Python so thank you!

Comment: point of order: brew will complain if you try and uninstall libxml2 *before* libxslt, because the former is required by the latter. Switching the order of the uninstalls worked for me

Answer (score 3):

What worked for was installing libxml2 with --with-python in brew command

```
brew install --with-python libxml2
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from  kylehunt let me fix an issue that some how started to show up after I ran "brew upgrade" after upgrading to macOS Catalina:

If you happen to see things like

```
Error: libxml2: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libxml2.rb:53: syntax error, unexpected <<
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
^~
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libxml2.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end
...              "--with-history",
...                              ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libxml2.rb:55: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end
...            "--without-python",
...                              ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libxml2.rb:57: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end
...               "--with-python",
...
```

It means you should run

```
brew edit libxml2
```

To fix the config file as it might have been broken by merge conflicts during upgrade. Look for <<<<< in the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, libxml2 was installed fine but it was not on my python import path. After editing my PYTHONPATH like so:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/
```

I was able to import libxml2.

```bash
$ python3
>>> import libxml2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libxml2'
>>> ^D

$ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages
$ python3
>>> import libxml2
>>>
```