# install libxml2 on osx yosemite

Tags: python, osx-yosemite, libxml2

On osx 10.10.5 Yosemite I've installed libxml2 using brew. The installation went fine. But when I try to use the package with python, the compiler keeps giving me this error: "ImportError: No module named libxml2"

Then I've tried to install it with pip. This went fine also but I still get the error in Python..
Next I used this command: **"sudo gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/lib"**

This installation succeeds with '1 gem installed' but in Python is still can't use the xml library libxml2...

What goes wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homebrew install libxml2 with python modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054972/homebrew-install-libxml2-with-python-modules)

Comment: You can try the solution offered to this other question. I don't work on osx, so I don't know if this is common there, but it surprises me you are trying to use tools for Ruby. Wouldn't be easier to use pip?

Comment: I tried the solution offered but this gives me a fatal python error at the moment the libxml2 gets imported into python... **"Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread"